# Run gtk program as regular user from a script running as root

Tags: linux, bash

I have put together a little script to copy pictures from the sd card run through udev and systemd service.
When it's complete I wanted it to open the file manager to the photo directory but since the script is running as root this makes problems.
How to get around this?

I am already using this script I found to display a notification, should I just make the same for the file manager? It seem a bit hacky and dirty.

```
#!/bin/sh
user=`whoami`
pids=`pgrep -u $user polybar`
title=$1
text=$2
timeout=$3
icon=$4

if [ -z "$title" ]; then
 echo You need to give me a title >&2
 exit 1
fi
if [ -z "$text" ]; then
 text=$title
fi
if [ -z "$timeout" ]; then
 timeout=60000
fi

for pid in $pids; do
 # find DBUS session bus for this session
 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=`grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS \
 /proc/$pid/environ | sed -e 's/DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=//'`
 # use it

 #icon hack:
 if [ -z $icon ]; then
 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS \
 notify-send -u low -t $timeout "$title" "$text"
 else
 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS \
 notify-send -u low -t $timeout -i "$icon" "$title" "$text"
 fi
done
```

Comment: [chown](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chown.1.html) ?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/93385/run-part-of-a-bash-script-as-a-different-user

Comment: damn i realize now i tried su, gksu -u but no regular su
thanks oguzismail

Comment: but still it's not the same ar running as user, graphic settings are different and it opens a new window instead of a new tab.
Is there not a way to launch the same exact as a user?

Comment: @RKon `chown` to user and run as user, and when needed use `sudo` before the command - but you'll have to insert a password, so you'll lose some automation.

Comment: @samthegolden what file/folder do I chown as user? if you mean the script itself i cannot as there are commands which need to be run as root.

Comment: @RKon chown the file and, as I said, use `sudo` in each command that needs root - is very morous, better use the `sudo su -` which is done once.